# How a make an application accessible to all users installed by Visual studio MSI?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer

I have built a MSI for my application which was written using C# Windows Forms. After installing, it is only accessible to the local admins on a server. How to make it accessible to all users?

Installed files are stored in `C:/Program Files(x86)/MyApp`

Comment: "To the local admins on a server", who do you expect it to be available to? Non-admins on the same machine or someone else (like all members of a network group)?

Comment: You'll need to say what you mean in more detail. If you run it and fails for limited users then figure out why. Does it have an elevation manifest? Does it try to access data in locations restricted to limited users (such as update files in Program Files folder) ?  The bottom line is that if you want the app to be useable to all users then it needs to not access data in locations restricted to limited users. Installing with an MSI does not allow limited users to violate system security.